# How can ı do if is true when my url address

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello everyone ı want to control my url address in my code ı want to redirect when url its true

```
if (data.is_okey && **URL** == true) {
      window.location.replace('https://google.com.tr');
}
```

Comment: How do you determine if the URL is true - what does that mean to you?

Comment: Also, you may want to use `window.location` instead, you create an item in your history that can direct you back.

Comment: Using `javascript` or `php`?

Comment: with javascript for example url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

Comment: For example
Let me go to google page when i come to stackoverflow address as url

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to check if a url is equal to a unique/decided one?

For example;

```js
let checkUrl = "/login"

let url = window.location.pathname;

if(data.is_okey && url != checkUrl) {
  window.location.replace("/login")

}
```

If you want sth like this. Please try it or explain with more details.

Comment: if (data.is_okey && window.location.pathname != "/google/") {
        window.location.replace('/google/');
        }
ı fixed like this thank you I just added "/" at the end

Comment: Emre, can you please confirm my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The current address in your browser is available with the variable `window.location.href`

So you should write:

```
if (data.is_okey && window.location.href == "**SOME URL YOU'D LIKE TO BE TRUE**") {
  window.location.replace('https://google.com.tr');
}
```

Comment: I added like this but its goes into an infinite loop

Comment: @Emre what's the url you're testing against?

Comment: if (data.is_okey && window.location.pathname != "/google/") { window.location.replace('/google/');
 }
ı fixed like that thank you for help
@y_nk